# How to execute specific regex substitution on selected lines in visual mode in vim

Tags: vim, ide

I want to replicate the VS code feature of 'highlight and comment out code' (usually bound to keys `SHIFT + /`) in `vim`.

I can run `:g//s/^/\/\/ /` in normal mode to prepend `//` at the start of every line. I just want to put a constraint on this so it only applies the substitution to lines highlighted in visual mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visually select all the lines (using `V`), then hit `:`.
This will give you `:'<,'>` which is the range of your visual selection.
Then you can add your vim command to it.

I would recommend the following method if you wish to not use plugins.

```
:'<,'>normal I//
```

Which is not a substitution.
If you want a really nice vim plugin that does this task in a `vim` manner, check out tpope's [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) which is an essential in my opinion.

Comment: Note  that any visual mode can be used, here: `v`, `V`, or `<C-v>`.

Answer (score 0):

> I can run `:g//s/^/\/\/ /` in normal mode to prepend `//` at the start of every line.

Well, that would be an unnecessarily complicated way to do it and your command wouldn't really work anyway.

- `:g//` either matches nothing or it matches the previous search. What you want, here, is probably something like `:g/^/` or `:g/$/`.
- A simple substitution on the whole buffer would be much simpler and much faster:

  ```
  :%s/^/\/\/ /
  ```

  Using `:help :global` in this context provides no value (you want to operate on every line anyway) and is considerably slower (we are talking thousands of times slower)
- You can use alternative separators to avoid all that backslashing:

  ```
  :%s@^@// @
  ```
- The last separator is not even needed:

  ```
  :%s@^@// <-- there is a space, here
  ```
- And the kicker: you can enter command-line mode from visual mode like you would do from normal mode, by pressing `:`. So you can simply make your visual selection, press `:`, and run your substitution:

  ```
  v                    " enter visual mode
  <motion>             " expand the selection
  :                    " press :
  :'<,'>               " Vim inserts the range covering the visual selection for you
  :'<,'>s@^@// <CR>    " perform your substitution
  ```